# Should I use integer or string to declare this attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm building an app with Ruby on Rails to mesure demographic variables. Right now, I have a doubt about how to declare the type of data from two attributes of a model (stats) that belongs to a users model. This attributes are "genere" and "civil status". I know that elements could be string data but if I pretend make some statistics with this info, **would it be more convenient declare this data like integer?**, that is to say, that is nominative data in statistic so a number is enough for represent an status or a genere, ie. 1 -> femenin  / 2 -> masculin.

I'll appreciate to much your advice. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would always go with a descriptive value, even if it is something as simple as 'M' / 'F', but it's up to you. Think about clarity and maintainability. A database full of numeric values can be very hard to read in a support environment.

Comment: i think it's better to use strings on your db and `to_sym` on your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enums](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) which are integer bitmasks are often a good way for attributes where there are a definite amount of choices and where add/removing options is a developer level concern.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  enum gender: [:undisclosed, :male, :female, :other]
end
```

This would store gender in an integer column with the values 0-3. The column will be much faster to scan and index than a string column.

It also saves you the hassle of whitelisting acceptable string values and writing scopes based on the value.

You can just do `Person.female` to get a scope.

Comment: On a side note both gender and civil status are political hot potatoes and you should be aware of any legal issues / requirements like providing an `other` option.

Comment: Thanks Max, I have that in mind and is a good idea provide `other` option.

Comment: One more thing, how can I declare `enum` in the terminal when I generate the model? `rails generate model Stat genere:enum civil_status:enum` Is that right?